# Rails on create transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, transactions

On creating a new user (in my user model) i want to create a stripe customer as well. The two actions must only be completed if they succeed together (like i don't want a customer without a user and vice versa). For this reason I figured it would be a good idea to wrap them in a transaction. However, I must not be doing it correctly. I do not believe I am properly overwriting the create method. If anyone has a suggestion as a better way to do this or what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
  def create
    User.transaction do
      super
      create_stripe_customer(self)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.transaction do
      super
      delete_stripe_customer(self)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I generally use transaction blocks as a critical section with database lock to prevent race condition. In your case, will there be any problem if you  call `create_stripe_customer` in your `after_create` callback on User model ? If create_stripe_customer fails then your User creation should be rolled back as well.

Comment: I am following. somebody must be having a good answer to this question.

Comment: will failure of the after_creation method cause a rollback? if so that is perfect and would solve my issue. I had that initially, but was unsure if failure caused a rollback or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research into your question and using after_create seems to be ok as long as an exception is raised if it fails. That will rollback the transaction as well. Just use the default callbacks.

[Here is a good answer related to the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241259/3243794)

Comment: Thank you. I looked into that as well after Vijay's suggestion above and it seems to perform the needed results. Thank you both for your help!